# android.mk shared library not found

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared

I tried to compile a shared library and an executable which use these library.
All sources and headers are in the same directory.
I use these Android.mk

## ==================libsample.so

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)


LOCAL_MODULE := libsample

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS = optional

LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libsample.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

## =======================tstsample

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)


LOCAL_MODULE := tstsample

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARY := libsample

LOCAL_CFLAGS :=-w

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  cmd.c main.c test.c

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

## ===================================

I obtained these error :
**error: undefined reference to** "each function of my library"

My library is compiled and put in the directory :
:
out/target/product/boadname/system/lib/

I also copied this library in the current directory. but I obtained the same error.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

If this was not a typo while copying your `Android.mk` to SO, then the following `sed` command should resolve your problem:

s/LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARY/LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES/